# split fill in ggplot geom_tile (or heatmap): two colors by third value

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, heatmap

I have categorical data that I'd like to map the frequency of using a heatmap (geom_tile), much like the example below:

```
data("mtcars")
freq <- data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear, mtcars)) #count number of 4,6,8 cyl cars by gear
ggplot(freq, aes(cyl, gear)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Freq)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue")
```

[image: standard frequency count heatmap]

**But I'd like to split each tile according to the proportion of significant or non-significant results (0-1 values).** In this example, I would generate the same frequency count but differentiate between automatic and manual transmission (`am`)

```
freq_am <- data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear + am, mtcars))
print(freq_am)
   #cyl gear am Freq
      4    3  0    1
      6    3  0    2
      8    3  0   12
      4    4  0    2
      6    4  0    2
      8    4  0    0
      4    5  0    0
      6    5  0    0
      8    5  0    0
      4    3  1    0
      6    3  1    0
      8    3  1    0
      4    4  1    6
      6    4  1    2
      8    4  1    0
      4    5  1    2
      6    5  1    1
      8    5  1    2
```

The resulting heatmap would have (for example) *blue* for values of `am==0` and *red* for `am==1`. Each tile would be divided (along a diagonal?) according to the proportion of cars of that type that are automatic (`am==0`) or manual (`am==1`). The shades of blue and red would be proportionate to the count, just as the gradient already reflects.

*For example:*

- the top left tile (4,5) would be completely light red because all of the 4-cyl, 5-gear cars (count = 2) are manual
- the middle left tile (4,4) would be 1/4 blue and 3/4 red because 25% of the 4-gear, 4-cyl cars are automatic (count = 2) and 75% are manual (count = 6)
- the bottom left tile (4,3) would be completely lightest blue because all of the 4-cyl, 3-gear cars (count = 1) are automatic

Comment: According to `?mtcars` `am` is defined as _Transmission (0 = automatic, 1 = manual)_. In your question you have defined _automatic (`am==1`) or manual (`am==0`)_  and _blue for values of `am==1` and red for `am==0`_ which is just the other way around.  Please, can you [edit] your Q and clarify? - Thank you.

Comment: fixed. thanks for offering the clarification and the solution!

Answer (score 5):

This is a second and hopfully complete attempt to answer the question by manipulating the frequency counts so that they become negative for `am==1`. The difference to the [first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794581/3817004) is that `geom_col(position = "fill")` is used instead of `geom_tile()` for plotting.

Note: I didn't edited [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794581/3817004) because the OP has already commented on it and I might delete that first and incomplete answer, eventually.

### Preparing the data

```
freq_am <-data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear + am, mtcars))
freq_am$Freq_am <- freq_am$Freq * (-1)^as.integer(as.character(freq_am$am))
```

This creates a new column `Freq_am` where `Freq` counts are multiplied with `-1` if `am == 1` (manual). Using exponentiation by a logical value is a trick to avoid `ifelse`.

### Plotting

There are two possibilities to achieve the desired heatmap-like appearance.

#### Variant 1

```
p <- ggplot(freq_am, (aes(x = cyl, y = Freq, fill = Freq_am))) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 1) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2() +
  facet_grid(gear ~ ., as.table = FALSE, switch = "y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
p
```

This creates a stacked bar chart of `Freq` vs `cyl` using `geom_col()` where the bars are stretched vertically (`position = "fill"`) and horizontally (`width = 1`) to fill the plotting area. In addition, the `expand = c(0, 0)` parameter to the `scale` functions tells `ggplot` to *not* expand the axes as usual. Note that the x-axis is discrete as `xtabs()` has coerced `cyl` to factor.

`facet_grid()` is used to simulate an y-axis with the `grid` values in increasing order (`as.table = FALSE`). `switch = "y"` moves the panel strips to the left side.

`scale_fill_gradient2()` uses a convenient diverging colour scheme by default so that the count of cars with automatic transmission appears in blue and the count of cars with manual transmission in red.

[image]

Now, we need to remove all decorations and spaces which aren't needed for a heatmap. Finally, the y-axis label is renamed:

```
p + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()
          , axis.ticks = element_blank()
          , axis.text.y = element_blank()
          , strip.background = element_blank()
          , panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")
) + 
  ylab("gear")
```

[image]

The downside of this approach is the lack of borders between tiles. So, it is difficult to distinguish the share of counts if adjacent tiles have the same colour as, e.g.,  the 6-cyl, 3-gear and 4-gear, resp., tiles.

#### Variant 2

This variant adds borders between the tiles. The width of the borders can be flexibly adjusted:

```
p <- ggplot(freq_am, (aes(x = 1, y = Freq, fill = Freq_am))) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2() +
  facet_grid(gear ~ cyl, as.table = FALSE, switch = "both") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
p
```

Here, we use `facet_grid()` for both directions. For each panel, `Freq` is plotted vs a dummy variable `1` using `geom_col()` as above. As the dummy variable `1` is numeric we don't need the `width` parameter to `geom_col()`. Both axes are continuous now.

[image]

Again, we need to remove some of the decorations and to rename the labels on the x and y-axes:

```
p + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()
        , axis.ticks = element_blank()
        , axis.text = element_blank()
        , strip.background = element_blank()
        # , panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt")
  ) + 
  xlab("cyl") + ylab("gear")
```

[image]

Now, we do have a heatmap with borders between the tiles. In order to remove the borders or adjust the width, you can uncomment the line with `panel.spacing` and change the value.

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented a new geom GeomSplitTile that allows to plot *two** related values in each field of a matrix plot. Here I modified it to fulfill your "space filling scaled to proportion" requirement:

```r
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

# A diagonally split version of GeomTile
# by [jan-glx](https://github.com/jan-glx), 
# based on ggplot2::GeomTile by the [ggplot2 authors](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/graphs/contributors)

draw_key_split_tile <- function(data, params, size) {
  
  data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% 1
  data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% 1
  data$frac<- data$frac %||% params$frac %||% 0.5
  data$width[is.na(data$width)] <- 1
  data$height[is.na(data$height)] <- 1
  data$frac[is.na(data$frac)] <- 0.5
  if (isTRUE(data$split)) {
    x <- c(0, 1, 0)
    y <- c(0, 1, 1)
  } else {
    x <- c(0, 1, 1)
    y <- c(0, 1, 0)
  }
  x <- 0.5 + (x-0.5) * data$width
  y <- 0.5 + (y-0.5) * data$height
  
  grid::polygonGrob(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    default.units = "npc",
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha)
    )
  )
}


geom_split_tile <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                            stat = "identity", position = "identity",
                            ...,
                            linejoin = "mitre",
                            na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA,
                            inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomSplitTile,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = rlang:::list2(
      linejoin = linejoin,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

GeomSplitTile <- ggproto(
  "GeomSplitTile", GeomPolygon,
  extra_params = c("na.rm"),
  
  setup_data = function(data, params) {
    data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% resolution(data$x, FALSE)
    data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% resolution(data$y, FALSE)
    data$frac<- data$frac %||% params$frac %||% 0.5
    data$split <- as.factor(data$split %||% params$split %||% FALSE)
    
    K = 5
    n <- nrow(data)
    z <- pmin(data$frac, 0.5)*2
    zz <- pmin(1-data$frac, 0.5)*2
    
    new_data <- data.frame(
      x = rep(data$x, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * as.vector(rbind(-1,  1, 1, zz, -z)) * rep(data$width / 2, each=K),
      y = rep(data$y, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * as.vector(rbind(-1, -1, 1, z, -zz)) * rep(data$height / 2, each=K),
      group = rep(seq_len(n), each=K)
    )
    new_data <- cbind(new_data, data[rep(seq_len(n), each = K), setdiff(colnames(data), c("x", "y", "group")), drop = FALSE])
    new_data
  },
  
  default_aes = aes(fill = "grey20", colour = NA, linewidth = 0.1, linetype = 1,
                    alpha = NA, width = NA, height = NA, frac =0.5),
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "split"),
  
  draw_key = draw_key_split_tile
)

scale_split <- function(..., scale_name="scale_direction", palette = function(n) if(n>2) error(paste0(scale_name, " can handle at most 2 levels")) else c(FALSE, TRUE)) discrete_scale(aesthetics = "split", scale_name=scale_name, palette = palette, ... )
```

Usage

```r
data("mtcars")
freq <- data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear, mtcars))
freq_am <- data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear + am, mtcars))
freq_am <-merge(freq, freq_am, by = c("cyl", "gear"), suffixes = c("_total","_am"))


ggplot(freq_am, aes(cyl, gear, fill = Freq_am, split = am, frac=Freq_am/Freq_total)) +
  geom_split_tile(data = freq_am[freq_am$am==1, ], aes()) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()+
  geom_split_tile(data = freq_am[freq_am$am==0, ] ,aes(fill=Freq_am, frac=Freq_am/Freq_total)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = scales::muted("red")) +
  scale_split(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=c(scales::muted("red"),"steelblue")))) +
  NULL
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This should be exactly what you requested. However keep in mind that a good graphic is easy to understand which can most easily be achieved by sticking to the standard plots.

Answer (score 1):

This is a first attempt to find an (incomplete) answer to the Q by manipulating the frequency counts so that they become negative for `am==0`.

Note that the question is not fully clear. `?mtcars` defines `am` as

> Transmission (0 = automatic, 1 = manual).

while the OP has defined

> automatic (`am==1`) or manual (`am==0`)

which is just the other way around. In addition, the OP has requested the heatmap to show *blue* for values of `am==1` and *red* for `am==0`.

### Preparing the data

```
freq_am <-data.frame(xtabs(~cyl + gear + am, mtcars))
freq_am$Freq_am <- -freq_am$Freq * (-1)^as.integer(as.character(freq_am$am))
freq_am$gear_am <- factor(paste(as.character(freq_am$gear), as.character(freq_am$am), sep = "_"))

freq_am
#freq_am
#   cyl gear am Freq Freq_am gear_am
#1    4    3  0    1      -1     3_0
#2    6    3  0    2      -2     3_0
#3    8    3  0   12     -12     3_0
#4    4    4  0    2      -2     4_0
#5    6    4  0    2      -2     4_0
#6    8    4  0    0       0     4_0
#7    4    5  0    0       0     5_0
#8    6    5  0    0       0     5_0
#9    8    5  0    0       0     5_0
#10   4    3  1    0       0     3_1
#11   6    3  1    0       0     3_1
#12   8    3  1    0       0     3_1
#13   4    4  1    6       6     4_1
#14   6    4  1    2       2     4_1
#15   8    4  1    0       0     4_1
#16   4    5  1    2       2     5_1
#17   6    5  1    1       1     5_1
#18   8    5  1    2       2     5_1
```

Note that `xtabs()` has coerced `am` to factor:

```
str(freq_am$am)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
```

To convert `am` back to numeric we have to use `as.integer(as.character(freq_am$am))`. (You may convert the level numbers directly to the original numeric values by using `(as.integer(am) - 1)` but that's less save.)

`gear_am` will be used as new y-axis when plotting the heatmap.

### Plotting

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(freq_am, aes(cyl, gear_am, fill = Freq_am)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

`scale_fill_gradient2()` uses a convenient diverging colour scheme by default.
The tiles for `gear` on the y-axis have now been split up into tiles with `am==0` and `am==1`.

[image]

### "Incomplete" answer

The OP has requested that the now split-up tiles should be completely filled even if there are zero counts. This could be achieved by further manipulating `freq_am`. However, I find the current chart communicates the result in a clear, unamibiguous way.

Comment: This is a great start, but I find it difficult to interpret. The boxes that are now discrete (e.g. `(4,5_1)` vs.`(4,5_0)`) are dichotomous values of one characteristic (`am`). This graphic doesn't guide the viewer to compare those values. I suggested splitting tiles into proportions to make that contrast more clear, but maybe this requires a different graphical approach altogether.