# Subdivide tiles in ggplot2 geom_tile into quarters

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geom-tile

I am trying to create a more elegant correlation plot for seasonal data using ggplot2 and geom_tile(). I want to split each tile in the plot into four quadrants (one quadrant for each seasonal value).

I already have code to plot each season's correlations separately:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# simplified data for 1 season
dat.season1 <- data.frame(Var1 = c("species2", "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                            "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                            "species4", "species5", "species5"),
                          Var2 = c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species1",
                                            "species2", "species2", "species2",
                                            "species3", "species3", "species4"),
                          value = runif(10, -1, 1))

#plot Season 1
my.colors = colorRampPalette(c("#00002d", '#001a6d', '#99cce2','#ffffff', "#FED18A",'#fda416', "#ff6600"),
                             space = "rgb")

colorLevels<-9
cols_to_use= my.colors(colorLevels)

ggplot(data = dat.season1, mapping = aes_string(x = "Var2",y = "Var1", fill = "value")) +
  geom_tile(color = "gray60") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  guides(size = "none")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), position = 'top') +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), limits = rev) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = cols_to_use,
                       space = "Lab",
                       guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour = "gray60", frame.linewidth = 2))
```

This gives me a plot that looks like this:
[Example single season correlation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0uX4.png)

What I want is a plot that looks like this:
[example_subdivided_seasonal_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCVNC.png)

However, I have searched stackoverflow and googled, but can't figure out a way to subdivide each tile into quadrants based on a factor column.

Here is a sample of the combined seasonal dataset:

```
dat.season2 <- data.frame(Var1 = c("species2", "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species4", "species5", "species5"),
                          Var2 = c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species1",
                                   "species2", "species2", "species2",
                                   "species3", "species3", "species4"),
                          value = runif(10, -1, 1))

dat.season3 <- data.frame(Var1 = c("species2", "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species4", "species5", "species5"),
                          Var2 = c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species1",
                                   "species2", "species2", "species2",
                                   "species3", "species3", "species4"),
                          value = runif(10, -1, 1))

dat.season4 <- data.frame(Var1 = c("species2", "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species3", "species4", "species5",
                                   "species4", "species5", "species5"),
                          Var2 = c("species1", "species1", "species1", "species1",
                                   "species2", "species2", "species2",
                                   "species3", "species3", "species4"),
                          value = runif(10, -1, 1))

all.dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(season1 = dat.season1, season2 = dat.season2,
                                  season3 = dat.season3, season4 = dat.season4),
                                  .id = "Season")
```

I found a couple threads that get close ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506324/split-fill-in-ggplot-geom-tile-or-heatmap-two-colors-by-third-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107666/generating-split-color-rectangles-from-ggplot2-geom-raster)), but neither of them splits each tile into quadrants.

The second seems the most promising, giving a plot that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM17p.png).

But I can't figure out how to modify the code in the answer to give quadrants instead of vertical or horizontal bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use facetting, i.e. facet by `Var1` and `Var2`, map your  seasons on "x" and "y" and use some styling to get rid of the axes and süacing between the panels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

all.dat1 <- all.dat |>
  mutate(
    x = if_else(Season %in% paste0("season", c(1, 3)), 1, 2),
    y = if_else(Season %in% paste0("season", c(1, 2)), 1, 2),
    across(c(x, y), factor)
  )

season_labels <- all.dat1 |> 
  distinct(Season, x, y) |> 
  mutate(Var1 = "species2", Var2 = "species1")

ggplot(data = all.dat1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "gray60") +
  geom_text(data = season_labels, aes(label = Season), color = "white") +
  facet_grid(Var1 ~ Var2, switch = "y") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  guides(size = "none") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), limits = rev) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = cols_to_use,
    space = "Lab",
    guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour = "gray60", frame.linewidth = 2)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
    strip.background = element_rect(color = "black")
  )
```

[image]