# Assign values based on reverse combination of two columns

Tags: r, matrix, insert, reverse, tile

Following this question, [Multiple values in one tile with geom_tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78024867/multiple-values-in-one-tile-with-geom-tile/78024957#78024957) and matrix plot, I'd like the tile attributes in `agreement_num` to be symmetrical, i.e. for the reverse pair combination, I'd like to plot the same `agreement_num`. I'm creating a new question since this entails finding the reverse combination of pairs, assigning the corresponding `agreement_num`  and then inserting new rows for each combination and `agreement_num`. E.g. from Kazakhstan to Kyrgyzstan there are six rows and six unique `agreement_num`. The expected output would be to have these rows in the dataframe:

```
from        to          weight          agreement_num
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    51
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    176
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    58
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    224
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    133
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    135
```

to be able to plot the same tile attribute for the reverse country combination in the matrix plot.

I've managed to get quite far to create the data below, but cannot figure out the last steps of inserting new rows and assigning the `agreement_num`  for each row:

```
# Create empty vectors to store values
oneway <- logical(nrow(plot_data))
additional_value <- list()

# Iterate over each row of the data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(plot_data)) {
  # Find indices of reverse pairs
  reverse_indices <- which(plot_data$from == plot_data$to[i] & plot_data$to == plot_data$from[i] & seq_len(nrow(plot_data)) != i)
  
  # Assign the oneway value
  oneway[i] <- length(reverse_indices) > 0
  
  # Assign additional value based on reverse combination
  if (oneway[i]) {
    # Add the additional values from the "agreement_num" column of the reverse pairs
    additional_value[[i]] <- unique(plot_data$agreement_num[reverse_indices])
  } else {
    # Assign NA if oneway is FALSE
    additional_value[[i]] <- NA
  }
}

# Add the vectors as new columns to the data frame
plot_data$oneway <- oneway
plot_data$additional_value <- additional_value
```

Reproducible data:

```
plot_data <- structure(list(from = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Afghanistan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Uzbekistan"
), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L), levels = c("Afghanistan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Uzbekistan"
), class = "factor"), weight = c(1291072130433.34, 480160896152.234, 
480160896152.234, 480160896152.234, 480160896152.234, 480160896152.234, 
480160896152.234, 3474907531417.02, 3474907531417.02, 3474907531417.02, 
867103764128.709, 867103764128.709, 7791981051421.92, 7791981051421.92, 
133799551.098735, 1102379004.66647), agreement_num = c(NA, 51L, 
176L, 58L, 224L, 133L, 135L, 58L, 51L, 224L, 51L, 224L, 51L, 
224L, NA, NA), com.x = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), com.y = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this, would be happy to get suggestions.

```
Example of expected output: 

plot_data

from        to          weight          agreement_num
Kazakhstan  Afghanistan 1.291072e+12    NA
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     51
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     176
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     58
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     224
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     133
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     135
[other rows]
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    NA

desired output

from        to          weight          agreement_num
Kazakhstan  Afghanistan 1.291072e+12    NA
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     51
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     176
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     58
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     224
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     133
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     135
[other rows]
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    51
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    176
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    58
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    224
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    133
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    135

not desired output

from        to          weight          agreement_num
Kazakhstan  Afghanistan 1.291072e+12    NA
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     51
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     176
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     58
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     224
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     133
Kazakhstan  Kyrgyzstan  4.801609e+1     135
Afghanistan Kazakhstan  1.291072e+12    NA #(don't want this row because Afghanistan    Kazakhstan is not represented in plot_data)
[other rows]
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    51  
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    176
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    58
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    224
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    133
Kyrgyzstan  Kazakhstan  1.337996e+08    135
```

Adding the code for plotting:

```
# Set agreement_num as factor

plot_data$agreement_num <- as.factor(plot_data$agreement_num)

# Allow multiple tiles

plot_data <- plot_data |>
  mutate(
    x = as.numeric(from),
    y = as.numeric(to),
    ymin = y - .5, ymax = y + .5
  ) |>
  mutate(
    n = n(),
    xmin = x + scales::rescale(row_number(),
                               from = c(1, unique(n) + 1),
                               to = .5 * c(-1, 1)
    ),
    xmax = x + scales::rescale(row_number() + 1,
                               from = c(1, unique(n) + 1),
                               to = .5 * c(-1, 1)
    ),
    .by = c(from, to)
  )


# Create color palette

par(mar=c(0,0,1,0))

coul <- brewer.pal(9, "Set3") 

# Plot
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = from, y = to, fill = agreement_num)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = coul) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Community 2") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=17),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 12, angle = 270,
      hjust = 0, vjust = 0
    ),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
    aspect.ratio = 1
  )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think an `NA` in the `agreement_num` column suggests that's a pair we need to reverse and augment ...

```
library(dplyr)
plot_data |>
  filter(is.na(agreement_num)) |>
  select(from=to, to=from, weight) |>
  inner_join(plot_data, by = c("from", "to")) |>
  rename(from=to, to=from, weight=weight.x) |>
  select(-weight.y) |>
  bind_rows(plot_data)
#              to       from       weight agreement_num com.x com.y
# 1    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08            51     2     2
# 2    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08           176     2     2
# 3    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08            58     2     2
# 4    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08           224     2     2
# 5    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08           133     2     2
# 6    Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08           135     2     2
# 7   Afghanistan Kazakhstan 1.291072e+12            NA     2     2
# 8    Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11            51     2     2
# 9    Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11           176     2     2
# 10   Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11            58     2     2
# 11   Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11           224     2     2
# 12   Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11           133     2     2
# 13   Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 4.801609e+11           135     2     2
# 14   Tajikistan Kazakhstan 3.474908e+12            58     2     2
# 15   Tajikistan Kazakhstan 3.474908e+12            51     2     2
# 16   Tajikistan Kazakhstan 3.474908e+12           224     2     2
# 17 Turkmenistan Kazakhstan 8.671038e+11            51     2     2
# 18 Turkmenistan Kazakhstan 8.671038e+11           224     2     2
# 19   Uzbekistan Kazakhstan 7.791981e+12            51     2     2
# 20   Uzbekistan Kazakhstan 7.791981e+12           224     2     2
# 21   Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan 1.337996e+08            NA     2     2
# 22   Uzbekistan Kyrgyzstan 1.102379e+09            NA     2     2
```

(Note that the augmented rows are *first*.)

Comment: That is really so simple and elegant - thank you. But is there a way to maintain the ```weight``` column for the ```from``` ```to``` combination? I see this is now also copied.

Comment: What should `weight` be?

Comment: The column ```weight``` should be maintained, so for Kyrgyzstan Kazakhstan 1.337996e+08 and not copied to 4.801609e+11 as in Kazakhstan Kyrgyzstan

Comment: Also, a problem when plotting now is that ggplot inserts new ```from``` ```to``` tiles, so the whole matrix becomes symmetrical. I only want the ```agreement_num``` to show and be symmetrical IF there is a tile in place. I've added my ggplot code to the question.

Comment: For your Kyr,Kaz pair, there are two values originally, how are you choosing one? Also, your plot code is not reproducible, we don't have (e.g.) `coul` or `xmin`.

Comment: I've updated the plot code so that it should be reproducible. For ```from``` Kyr ```to``` Kaz there is one value: 133799551, which I'd like maintained for that pair combination.

Comment: I see now that the suggested solution is actually not solving the issue. I only need new rows inserted when there is actually the reverse country combination present. @r2evans is there a way to update accordingly so not the entire matrix comes our as symmetric? E.g. ```from``` Afghanistan ```to``` Kazakhstan should not be included in the new dataframe, because that combination does not exist in the first place. I just want to assign ```agreement_num``` for the reverse country combinations that already exist in ```plot_data```.

Comment: I really don't understand. If `Afgh,Kaza` does not exist, then `Kaza,Afgh` will not be in the augmented data.

Comment: I added my desired output to the post, I hope this clarifies the question? @r2evans

Comment: Is it meaningful that the target pairs start with `agreement_num = NA`?

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it makes the right assumption @MoonS

Comment: That does it - exactly what I needed! The only last thing is that I don't really need row 21 anymore after having inserted the new rows. Thank you so much for your persistence. @r2evans